# Python Selenium Unable to locate element [NoSuchElementException] when using CLASS_NAME selector

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, classname, nosuchelementexception

When I try to use `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'classname')`, it will always return NoSuchElementException, unable to locate element.
But when I use ID and NAME on the same element, it worked! Only CLASS_NAME failed.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="login_field" class="form-control input-block js-login-field" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="username" autofocus="autofocus">
```

**And here is the script**

```
username1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"form-control input-block js-login-field")
username2 = driver.find_element(By.ID,"login_field")
print(username1)
print(username2)
```

Username1 failed, username2 pass.

I tried change to cssSelector:

`username1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.form-control input-block js-login-field"));`

I also tried change syntax:

`username1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME("input[class='form-control input-block js-login-field']"))`

But none of it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `By.CLASS_NAME` method in Selenium is designed to work with a single class name, not multiple.

The element has multiple classes: `form-control`, `input-block`, and `js-login-field`. You should select one of these classes to use with `By.CLASS_NAME`.

```
username1 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "form-control")
```

**Using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` for a Compound Class Name**

```
username1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-control.input-block.js-login-field")
```